# String + List in Python2 Function needed in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

There have been a lot of questions asked/answered on how to solve the "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" error, which is what I am getting. I am new to Python and am taking an online course that is being taught in Python2.7 (I believe) but I am writing in Python 3.

This is my current code:

```
 print bcolors.BOLD + self.name + "     " + str(self.hp) + "/" + str(self.maxhp) + " |" + bcolors.OKGREEN + "███████             " + "|      " \
          + str(self.mp) + "/" + str(self.maxmp) + " |" + bcolors.OKBLUE + "██████" + bcolors.ENDC + "|"
```

I know I need to change some of the + signs to commas since there are strings but I have tried basically every combination and am losing hope.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm really sorry if this was posted elsewhere but I did look everywhere - My lack of knowledge of python also didn't allow me to apply some of the other articles to this I don't think.

Comment: If this is python 3... you have another glaring problem with your code...

Comment: Hint: What is print in python3?

Comment: `I know I need to change some of the + signs to commas since there are strings` 

>> The `+` signs concatenate strings, so you're probably using it correctly.  

In python 2, commas tell the print command to not end with a `newline`. In python 3, trailing commas have been replaced with `print('hello!', end='')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by this question.

`print "Hello World"` with the space in between is Python 2.7 syntax; Python 3 uses `print("Hello World")`. If you commandline `which python` it should let you know which python you're using for the interpreter.

Also, in this case, that error means that you're adding a `str` and a `list` together. The only variables that do not have a `str` cast are `name` and the `bcolors` so check these two variables to see if they are lists. The error may not even be at this line.

If you want to join together items of a list, the correct syntax is as other answers have posted: `''.join([str(item) for item in _list])`.

Answer (score 0):

The plus signs are fine.

No parentheses for print is not

For example

```
print(bcolors.BOLD + self.name)
```

As for lists, you will want to `join()` it

Or you can combine this approach

```
print("".join([bcolors.BOLD, self.name]))
```